# Liquid Crystal LCD and serial monitor not playing well together

Tags: serial, lcd

On my Arduino Uno, when I'm not using the serial everything seems in order:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup()
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Prints");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Well");
}

void loop()
{
    delay(1000);
}
```

However the moment I open the serial port with:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

The problem starts.

Clearing the LCD does not clear it but prints a character with 4 horizontal lines. Trying to move the cursor will print a different  unrecognisable character. Sending things to the Arduino via the Serial port prints gibberish on the LCD.

[image: character with 4 horizontal lines]

Any idea why? Is there a way to work with the LCD and the serial port simultaneously? I require the serial port in order to control the Arduino from NodeJS.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup()
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Prints");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Well");

    Serial.begin(9600);

    while (!Serial)
    {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Native USB only
    }
}
    
void loop()
{
    lcd.clear(); // This will print 4 horizontal lines character instead of clearing
    delay(500); 
}
```

Comment: What type of Arduino?  On some pin 1 is one of the hardware serial pins. You can’t use that pin for other things like LCDs if you are using serial.

Comment: @Delta_G The board is Arduino Uno and you are right. Changing the pin from 1 to 3 solved the issue. Tnx! I wonder how many of 846,000 viewers of this youtube had the same issue? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZZynJLmTn8&pbjreload=101 :-)

Comment: I will make it an answer.  Please accept

Comment: @jsotola the question was downvoted so I thought perhaps I misrepresented the issue. I restored the previous title to your suggestion. tnx.

Comment: somebody probably downvoted the post because you did not check which pins are used by the serial port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an UNO pin 1 is one of the hardware serial pins.  You can’t use pin 0 or pin 1 for other things if you are using Serial in your code.

Even if you aren’t using Serial, you use pins 0 and 1 when uploading your code and having other things connected can mess up that process.  It’s generally advisable to stay away from pins 0 and 1 unless you absolutely must use them.